# Lua wxwidgets wxListCtrl

Tags: lua, wxwidgets

How do I obtain the index of a line when it is clicked?

```
lpanelList:Connect(ID_REL_LIST, wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_LEFT_CLICK,
function (event)
local number
number = GetIndex()                           --generates an error
frame:SetStatusText("REL LIST")
wx.wxMessageBox('Clicked on rel list.',
" Rel List Clicked ",
wx.wxOK + wx.wxICON_INFORMATION,
lpanelList)
end )
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetIndex()` is a method of `event`, so you should be using `event:GetIndex()`, but I don't think it's populated for mouse events (LEFT_CLICK). For mouse events you may need to use [wxListCtrl:FindItem](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ae46c0aa927816ae5b10afeea7a040e47) (if it's available through wxlua) to get the item closest to the position of the click. To get the coordinates of the click you can use `event:GetPoint()` (if available) or something like this:

```
local mousePos = wx.wxGetMousePosition() -- mouse pos on screen
local clientPos = lpanelList:ScreenToClient(mousePos)
```

Instead of using mouse events, you can also use `wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED`, in which case you can do `local index = event:GetIndex()` (I think this index is 0-based).

If you are using wxlua, I found the samples that are included with it (`samples/` folder) a good source of solutions supported with wxlua API.